# How in linux create two groups with?

Tags: linux

I need create two group of users one should have full access, second only read only.
Does it possible in linux? How to do it?

Comment: http://serverfault.com ?

Comment: `man groupadd` and `man useradd` should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do this twice

```
 groupadd <group-name>
```

then this to change permissions on a file or directory

```
 chmod <group-name>+||- <permissions> <file or directory name>
```

Hope this helps